# Pivoting data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like the following:

| Day | Minutes | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Play |
| 1 | 10 | Eat |
| 1 | 30 | Move |
| 1 | 50 | Transport |
| 2 | 0 | Play |
| 2 | 20 | Transport |
| 2 | 50 | Sleep |

Is it possible to pivot the table to have my Day as an index while the column names are the status and the values are the minutes?

Desired Output:

| Day | Play | Eat | Move | Transport | Play | Transport | Sleep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: This is the use case for dplyr::pivot_wider().

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr` (part of the `tidyverse`). You can supply the new column names using `names_from`, then you want to fill in the values with the data from `Minutes`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Status", values_from = "Minutes")
```

**Output**

```
    Day  Play   Eat  Move Transport Sleep
  <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int> <int>
1     1     0    10    30        50    NA
2     2     0    NA    NA        20    50
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Minutes = c(0L, 
10L, 30L, 50L, 0L, 20L, 50L), Status = c("Play", "Eat", "Move", 
"Transport", "Play", "Transport", "Sleep")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```